# Trying to get subtotal in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get subtotal in SQL Server using union and I was able to get the subtotal but I am looking to get it at the end of `companyID`. Right now I am getting in the middle and not exactly at the end of the company. Wondering if anyone knows how I can get the subtotal at the end of a `CompanyID`.

```
select distinct 
    Personid, 
    concat(rtrim(LastName),+ ', ',+ rtrim(FirstName)) as PersonName, 
    CompanyName, CompanyId, OrderId, JobTitle, 
    cast(TSPayRate as varchar) as PayRate, 
    cast(TSBillRate as varchar) as BillRate, 
    cast(RegHours as varchar) as TotalRegHours, 
    cast(OTHours as varchar) as TotalOTHours  
from
    timesheets TSV
where 
    CompanyId in ('000000001', '000000002') 
--group by Personid, Concat(rtrim(LastName),+ ', ',+ rtrim(FirstName)), CompanyName, CompanyId, orderid,JobTitle, PayRate, BillRate, reghours, othours

union all

select distinct  
    '  ', ' ', ' ', companyid, ' ', ' ', ' ', 
    cast('SUBTOTAL' as varchar),
    sum(RegHours) as TotalRegHours, 
    sum(OTHours) as TotalOTHours  
from
    timesheets TSV
where 
    CompanyId in ('000000001', '000000002')     
group by 
    companyid
order by 
    companyid
```

[image: current results]

[image: expected results]

Comment: Sample data and expected results, on a *consumable format* will help us help you. Good use of whitespace and line breaks in your code would really not go amiss either.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for that. I will work on the format for the future. I have uploaded an image of current results and expected results, hope that make it more clear

Comment: Order by the column you're putting "SUBTOTAL" under, then the numbers will appear before the subtotal line. Basically I'd wrap this union query into a CTE or subquery, and then use ORDER BY to sort the output.

Comment: Also I think the bottom query needs the column aliases too

Comment: Do you have duplicate records in the source? The DISTINCT is suspicious.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Thisjis why i said that the data needs to be consumable; we can't use the images of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force your subtotals into the results as desired by creating a column to sort on. In the example, I put your `UNION` query into a CTE. I added a column in both `SELECT`s called `CompanySortColumn`. In the main `SELECT`, I Order the results by `CompanyID`, then the added `CompanySortColumn`, then the `OrderID` and whatever you desire.

```
WITH prelim as (
  select distinct 
    Personid, 
    concat(rtrim(LastName),+ ', ',+ rtrim(FirstName)) as PersonName, 
    CompanyName, CompanyId, OrderId, JobTitle, 
    cast(TSPayRate as varchar) as PayRate, 
    cast(TSBillRate as varchar) as BillRate, 
    cast(RegHours as varchar) as TotalRegHours, 
    cast(OTHours as varchar) as TotalOTHours,  
    1 as CompanySortColumn  --Added column to force desired sort order with subtotals interjected at the "end" of each Company.
  from
    timesheets TSV
  where 
    CompanyId in ('000000001', '000000002') 
  --group by Personid, Concat(rtrim(LastName),+ ', ',+ rtrim(FirstName)), CompanyName, CompanyId, orderid,JobTitle, PayRate, BillRate, reghours, othours

  union all

  select distinct  
    '  ', ' ', ' ', companyid, ' ', ' ', ' ', 
    cast('SUBTOTAL' as varchar),
    sum(RegHours) as TotalRegHours, 
    sum(OTHours) as TotalOTHours ,
    2 as CompanySortColumn  --Added column to force desired sort order with subtotals interjected at the "end" of each Company.
  from
    timesheets TSV
  where 
    CompanyId in ('000000001', '000000002')     
  group by 
    companyid
)
  SELECT *
  FROM prelim
  ORDER BY CompanyID, CompanySortColumn, OrderID
```